# Core Data calculation and grouping on data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Example: I have the following data set:

```
date         eur   usd    aud
------------------------------
2015-01-01   0.5   1.0    1.5
2015-01-02   0.6   1.1    1.6
2015-01-03   0.4   1.0    1.3
           ....
2015-02-01   0.5   1.0    1.5
2015-02-02   0.6   1.1    1.6
2015-02-03   0.4   1.0    1.3
```

My goal is to calculate average ratio eur/usd eud/aud each week of the year. I'm expecting the following result:

```
avg eur / usd:
------------------
Week 1   0.5
Week 2   0.54
Week 3   0.4
```

To calculate eur / usd ration I've added `NSExpression`. Here is the code:

```
    let usdExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "usd")
    let eurExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "eur")
    let ratioExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "divide:by:", arguments: [usdExpression, eurExpression])
    let avgRatioExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "average:", arguments: [ratioExpression])
```

I add expression to fetch request. Now I'd to group by week. I don't store week in database (I only have date there). I've added `transient property` to my model and implemented logic there:

```
var weekOfYear {
   var numberOfWeek: Int?
   ...
   return "Week \(numberOfWeek)"
}
```

But I'm unable to group by this property. So are there any way I can receive grouped values? If no, seems like my expressions are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't group by a transient, because it isn't actually stored in the SQL. You could make your transient a persistent value and update all of the records in the store, then you can use it for fetching. This is likely the best approach as the week number doesn't change and is a small piece of data, also, as the data grows fetching into memory or running multiple fetches will take an increasing amount of time.